# Pandas DataFrame : extract unique component as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I extracted from bloomberg all the daily stocks component of the SP500 for 30 years in a dataframe with index as date and row components as stock.

Now i'll need to transform this dataframe with date as index and column as stocks, in order to pass it to the bloomberg api again to retrieve all stocks details

Here is an example of what I need to do :

I have currently this:

```
pd.DataFrame([['A','B',np.nan],['A','B','C'],['B','C','D']])

   0  1    2
0  A  B  NaN
1  A  B    C
2  B  C    D
```

and i'm looking to get this:

```
pd.DataFrame([[True,True,False,False],[True,True,True,False],[False,True,True,True]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])
       A     B      C      D
0   True  True  False  False
1   True  True   True  False
2  False  True   True   True
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.get_dummies`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).max(level=0).astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
       A     B      C      D
0   True  True  False  False
1   True  True   True  False
2  False  True   True   True
```

Comment: Thanks. Taking a while on a 7563x508 dataframe... I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

If you know beforehand what your stocks are (in your example `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`), you can do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B',np.nan],['A','B','C'],['B','C','D']])
stock_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df_new = pd.DataFrame([[X in df.iloc[i].unique() for i in range(len(df))] for X in stock_names]).transpose()
df_new.columns = stock_names
```